# How to write ::before / ::after inside anchor tag

Tags: html, css

How to write ::before inside anchor tag like this.

[image]

Comment: Through CSS...like this `a::before{content:""}` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbfhx7w2/)

Comment: When you inspect element the ::before pseudo tag shows up, it is not actually 'inside' the anchor tag rather it is done using css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see here is a **CSS pseudo-element**.

`::before` pseudo-element can be used to insert some content before the content of an element. eg - the following code will insert `This comes before...` before every paragraph.

```css
p::before {
  content: "This comes before...";
}
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is another paragraph</p>
```

For more information on CSS pseudo-elements, refer to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) link.

Answer (score 2):

which is used in CSS2 and The `::before` selector inserts something before the content of each selected element or elements.

Use the content property to specify the content to insert.

Also have `::after` which selector use to insert something after the content.

CSS

```
<style>
    p::before { 
    content: "User Name";
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>



<body>

<p>Karthik N </p>
<p>Sachith MW </p>

</body>
```

The Output will be displayed as follows :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) and [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) are called [psuedo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

::after and ::before lets you add some content to an element using the `content` property.

**Example**

```css
a::before {
  content: " Before content";
  margin-right: 10px;
}
a::after {
  content: "After content";
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Click Here </a>
```

Comment: i know they are pseudo elements, but i have seen them inside html code, and i dont understand the effect, take a look at the question, that is an html file, not a css one, like those of every answer